# How to access record elements and assign value to them?

Tags: vhdl, record

I've created a record in VHDL

```
type direction is record
  left : std_logic;
  right : std_logic;
end record direction;
```

And I have function that should return this record with assigned values to left and right of either 0 or 1.

That part of function looks like this:

```
begin

if (x = 0) then
    direction.left <= '0';
else
    direction.left <= '1';
end if;
....

return direction;
end;
```

but I keep getting error that it cannot be used as a prefix in a selected name. I've never worked with a record inside a function, so I feel like I'm doing something wrong while accessing the elements of record.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You should always give a [mcve]... The problem is probably that you are trying to assigning to the **type** instead of an **object** of that type... I.e. `signal direction_object : direction;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have defined is a `type`

A type is a descriptor to an item, usually a `signal` or a `variable`.

Common types in VHDL are `std_logic`, `std_logic_vector`, `integer`, etc... and you have the right to create your own type. The type direction you describe is OK.

To use it, you have to declare in your function a variable defined with this very type :

```
variable my_direction : direction;
```

Then you can use the variable `my_direction` in your function.

```
type direction is record
  left : std_logic;
  right : std_logic;
end record direction;

function my_func (x...) return direction is
  variable my_direction : direction;
begin

if (x = 0) then
    my_direction.left := '0';
else
    my_direction.left := '1';
end if;
....

return my_direction;
end;
```